# com object for OTA.dll not getting detected in python script

Tags: python

I just wanted to fetch data from QC using `OTA.dll` COM object from python.
I am using Pycharm IDE. But all the Quality Center objects is getting ignored as `OTA.dll` is not getting recognized. Please find my code below:

```
import os
import pywintypes
import win32com
from win32com.client import Dispatch, gencache, DispatchWithEvents, constants


from datetime import datetime
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

qcServer = "<QC_address>"
qcUser = "<uname>"
qcPassword = "<pwd>"
qcDomain = "<Domain>"
qcProject = "Project"
#qcTestCasePath = "Path\to\test\case"
#qcTestCaseNode = "test case node name"

# test case status names in hpqc
hpqc_status_pass = 'Passed'
hpqc_status_fail = 'Failed'
hpqc_status_no_run = 'No Run'
hpqc_status_not_completed = 'Not Completed'
hpqc_status_na = 'N/A'

# login to hpqc


td = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
td.InitConnectionEx(qcServer)
td.Login(qcUser,qcPassword)
td.Connect(qcDomain,qcProject)
if td.Connected:
    print("Logged in to " + qcProject)
else:
    print("ERROR: Connect failed to " + qcProject)
```

But when I am running above code using Pycharm its giving below error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/masooa/workspace/TestPythonProject/src/QC.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/masooa/workspace/TestPythonProject/src/QC.py", line 29, in <module>
    td = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could somebody please help me out. I really appreciate if someone can let me know how to resolve.

**NOTE**: In PythonWIn, In tool tab and then selecting Com browser option, listed the OTA library but python or IDE which I am using not detecting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Registered COM object not recognized by python's win32com.client.dispatch()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297381/registered-com-object-not-recognized-by-pythons-win32com-client-dispatch)